# Add server name to metrics for Datadog

Tags: java, datadog

I use [dropwizard metrics](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics) with [metrics-datadog](https://github.com/coursera/metrics-datadog).

Create reported like this:

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = new HttpTransport.Builder().withApiKey(API_KEY).build();

DatadogReporter reporter;
reporter = DatadogReporter.forRegistry(metrics)
            .withTransport(httpTransport)
            .withPrefix(PREFIX)
            .withTags(tags)
            .convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .convertDurationsTo(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .filter(MetricFilter.ALL)
            .build();

reporter.start(value, unit);
```

But there is no host(server name) param in datadog. How can I add host (server name) for metrics to filter them in datadog control panel? Metrics from default datadog agent has server name attribute.

Comment: Do you have a Datadog agent installed on that machine? If it is the case, you have a dogstatsd UDP server running locally that you can use to collect metrics. Just swap the `HTTPTransport` class with the `UDPTransport` one, and the agent will take care of setting the host name properly. It also avoids HTTP requests failures that might be tricky to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just should set hostname for `org.coursera.metrics.datadog.DatadogReporter.Builder`:

```
.withHost(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName())
```